# VF Remoting failed to call the apex method and onclick is not working?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

**VF Code :**

```
<apex:page controller="AYKE_FAQ_SearchController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
           <center> <button onclick="ThumbsUpCount(\'{!language}\',\'{!country}\',\'ka00E0000008RUZQA2\')">   <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.AYKE_ThumbsUP)}"/>  </button> </center>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <Script>
    function ThumbsUpCount(lang,country,faqid) {
                $("#search-faq-input").val('');
                $("#search-faq-input").attr("placeholder", "{!$Label.AYKE_FAQ_Search_the_FAQ}");
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.AYKE_FAQ_SearchController.getThumbsUpCount}',
                        lang,country,faqid,
                        function(result, event){
                        console.log('@@@@@@@@'+lang)
                            if (event.status) {
                                // on success 
                                alert('lang');                   
                            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                                // on exception 
                            } else {
                                // on error
                            }
                        }, 
                        {escape: true}
                    );
        }

    </Script>
</apex:page>
```

**Method :**

```
@RemoteAction
        global static string getThumbsUpCount(string language,string country,String faqid) {
        String searchquery = '';
        //if(  faqID != '' && language != '' && country!= '')  
        searchquery = 'select Description__c, ID, Title, Summary FROM FAQ__kav WHERE (PublishStatus=\'Online\' AND Language =\'' + language+ '\')' + ' AND id=\'' + faqID + '\'';
        FAQ__kav fqv = new FAQ__kav();
        fqv = database.query(searchquery);
        faqid = fqv.id;
        system.debug('########################' + fqv);
            FAQ_User_Rating_Summary__c fq = new FAQ_User_Rating_Summary__c();
            // Look for Existing FAQ Rating Summary
            list<FAQ_User_Rating_Summary__c> existingFAQ = new list<FAQ_User_Rating_Summary__c>([SELECT Id, Thumps_Up_Count__c FROM FAQ_User_Rating_Summary__c WHERE FAQ_Id__c=:faqid limit 1]);                                                         // Assuming there will be one Rating summary per FAQ.
            if( !existingFAQ.isEmpty() ){
                fq = existingFAQ.get(0);
                fq.Thumps_Up_Count__c = fq.Thumps_Up_Count__c != null ? fq.Thumps_Up_Count__c + 1 : 1; 
            }else{
                fq.Country__c = country;
                fq.FAQ_Id__c= fqv.id;
                fq.Language__c= language;
                fq.Thumps_Up_Count__c = 1;
            }
            upsert fq;
            return string.valueof(fq.Thumps_Up_Count__c);

    }
```

Need some help in fixing this

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console in your browser for error messages?

Comment: Have you tried to remove escape symbols if you have them in your code?

<button onclick="ThumbsUpCount('{!language}','{!country}','ka00E0000008RUZQA2')">

Comment: Uncaught Systax error: Invalid or unexpected error : (function(event){ThumbsUpCount(\'\',\'\',\'ka00E0000008RUZQA2\')
})

Comment: I have tried removing escape symboles got : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: No need esape symbols when it is in visual force code. onclick="ThumbsUpCount('{!language}','{!country}','ka00E0000008RUZQA2')"  .  Required when you use in javascript.

Comment: Your welcome ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @NITESH is right. I tried removing `\'` and it worked. Replace your button click code with below:

```
<center> <button onclick="ThumbsUpCount('{!language}','{!country}','ka00E0000008RUZQA2');">   <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.AYKE_ThumbsUP)}"/>  </button> </center>
```

Comment: Ya, But he had Previously issue with same problem, If you have time look at the chat discussion  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64935/discussion-between-thomas-and-nithesh-k  may be you can give him suggestion .

Comment: But the only problem now i have is instead of hard coded Id, need to have a realtime id.

Comment: @B1sfdc You'll need some list of `Id`'s iterated through `<apex:repeat>`, assigning unique id's and accessing it's value in JavaScript with that unique id. And I think that all together a different scenario. Give it a try and if you get stuck then start a new thread by posting a new question with proper code which you tried and explanation.